# Big O Notation - Prove (nlogn)^2 - 4 is O(n^4)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, asymptotics

first year student here,
I am having a bit of trouble dealing with logs when they are squared, and as such, difficulty with this text book problem, I am trying to gain an intuition to solve log problems, but there is not many examples on the internet about it, so It would be nice if someone could show me the way to solving this problem.

My Attempt:

```
C(n^4) >=(nlogn)^2 - 4

i assumed n > 0, so that n > log(n)
(n)^2 > (logn)^2
n^2 > log^2(n)
n^4 > n^2*log^2(n)

but i got stuck here since i didn't know how to continue my proof
I feel like it has to do with something related to how n^2 > log^2(n)
```

Comment: This is going to depend on which definition of Big-O you are using.  Since the statement is so obvious, you shouldn't treat this as a "prove the statement" type exercise, but rather a "prove that the definitions are sufficient to establish the statement" type exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sketch prove, it's not fully complete, but it should give you a hint:

Consider the function $f(x) = x - \log(x)\implies f'(x) = \frac{x - 1}{x}$, which is strictly positive for $x>1$, as such, $f(x)$ this function is strictly increasing on $(1,+\infty) \implies x > \log(x)\implies x^2 > x\log(x)\implies x^4 > \left(x^2\log(x)\right)^2\implies \left(x^2\log(x)\right) = O(x^4)$